# Saving a Parse User using Parse Cloud

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm trying to use Parse Cloud to save some changes to the current logged in user, but for some reason it results in `response.error()`.

I have reduced my code to this snippet just for testing purposes.

```
Parse.Cloud.define("createGroup", function(request, response) {
 var currentUser = Parse.User.current();
 currentUser.set("currentGroupId", "test");
 currentUser.save(null, {
          success: function(currentUser){
            response.success();
          },
          error: function(error){
            response.error("error " + error);
          }
        });
});
```

The error log message says `error [object Object]`.
I really have no idea what is wrong with my code, I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to place

```
Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
```

in your main.js to gain access to the Users table or the Installations table. If it doesn't work when called inside the function, you may have to call it outside of any function definitions

```
Parse.Cloud.define("createGroup", function(request, response) {
    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
    var currentUser = Parse.User.current();
    console.log(JSON.stringify(currentUser)); //make sure you are getting something here
    currentUser.set("currentGroupId", "test");
    currentUser.save(null, {
          success: function(currentUser){
            response.success();
          },
          error: function(error){
            response.error("error " + error);
          }
        });
});
```

Comment: I have tried using the masterkey but the error is still there. The console log is displaying the correct json object. I even removed the `currentUser.set("currentGroupId", "test");` but for some reason it will never `save()` successfully. Any ideas?

Comment: I solved the problem. Turns out I had a `beforeSave()` function that was causing the error. Thanks for the help!